# Register tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I was looking to make a tag synonym for [register](/questions/tagged/register) over on SO, in the context of turning it into [cpuregister](/questions/tagged/cpuregister) (there is also a [registers](/questions/tagged/registers) for the CPU ones).  There are a bunch of questions that are tagged [register](/questions/tagged/register), which should probably be tagged [registration](/questions/tagged/registration) because involving a registration for a website or the like.

Should I manually retag the ones involving CPU registers to [cpuregister](/questions/tagged/cpuregister) or [registers](/questions/tagged/registers) and then put the synonym in place for [register](/questions/tagged/register)?

Comment: No, wait for a mod to come along. Sidenote: in my eyes the `register` tag with the meaning if `registration` is useless.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more about the meaning of it, but it seems as though that camp has at least a majority of the questions under that tag.

Comment: Need to fix my glasses on making those tag symbols, thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I set up [cpu-registers](/questions/tagged/cpu-registers) with a synonym merge from [registers](/questions/tagged/registers), and I destroyed [register](/questions/tagged/register) as it was pretty much meaningless.

Comment: There probably was some data to be mined from `register` (most would have been retagged "user-registration" it seems), but this is still certainly an improvement.